# How to customize the ouput of Get-Windowsfeature path

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Actually, i'm looking to customize my output from `Get-Windowsfeature | select path`, and i'm stuck.

This is the ouput of simple command :

```
Path                                                                         
----                                                                         
Services de fichiers et de stockage                                                                                                          
Services de fichiers et de stockage\Services de fichiers et iSCSI                                                                            
Services de fichiers et de stockage\Services de fichiers et iSCSI\Serveur de fichiers                                                        
Services de fichiers et de stockage\Services de fichiers et iSCSI\BranchCache pour fichiers réseau                                           
.........
```

I'm looking to get the result like this (add the feature name of the path before the separator ";").

```
Path Needed
---- 

File and Storage Services [FileAndStorage-Services];;;;;;;;",

File and Storage Services [FileAndStorage-Services];File and iSCSI Services [File-Services];;;;;;;",

File and Storage Services [FileAndStorage-Services];File and iSCSI Services [File-Services];File Server [FS-FileServer];;;;;;",

File and Storage Services [FileAndStorage-Services];File and iSCSI Services [File-Services];BranchCache for Network Files [FS-BranchCache];;;;;;"
```

Anyone have an idea ?

In advance, thank you for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect case for `CalculatedProperties`, or a foreach loop.  I think foreach loops are easier to read so let's go with that approach.

```
$features = get-windowsFeature
forEach ($feature in $features){
    $joinedPath = $feature.Name, $feature.Path -join ";"
    Write-Output $joinedPath
}
```

You could make this shorter, but I think with each line doing one step, it's easy to understand.

Output looks like this:

```
Windows-TIFF-IFilter;Windows TIFF IFilter
WinRM-IIS-Ext;WinRM IIS Extension
WINS;WINS Server
Wireless-Networking;Wireless LAN Service
WoW64-Support;WoW64 Support
XPS-Viewer;XPS Viewer
```

Comment: You're welcome!  This also works if you add additional filters to the `Get-WindowsFeature` step, like `| where Status -eq "Installed"`, for instance.  Happy coding.